# Get a href from specific table cell without id using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, html-table, cell

I am a Javascript beginner. I have a table with links in every cell of last column. I need to go through that every cell and change the onclick function of a href that is in that cell. Initially the hrefs' ids are not known to me, so I cannot refer to them using ids. There is only one link in a cell. I would not like to use jQuery

This is how the cell looks like:

```
<td><a title="my title text" id="cell_id" href="#" class="someclass">Anchor</a></td>
```

Based on answers below i tried to construct something like this:

```
for (var i = 0 ;i<tbl.rows.length-1; i++) {
             tbl.rows[i].lastChild.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML="X1";
    }
```

But this does not work. Error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: I am asking this question because I have no idea how to create the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have "a" element inside the cell

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
```

or if you want to set attribute

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", "somelink.com");
```

something like this might work..its hard to help cause you dont provide some code to know what you are trying to do

```
var links = document.querySelector("table tr td:last-child");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
   links[i].setAttribute("href", "somelink.com");
}
```

Comment: I think essential would be to show how to use "this" mentioned by you to solve my problem :)

Comment: But this changes all links in the document and I want to change only the links in the table and only those that are in the last column, as there are also some other links in the table.

Comment: var links = document.querySelector("table tr td:last-child");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
   links[i].setAttribute("href", "somelink.com");
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using JQuery this can be accomplished like this:

```
$('table tr td:last-child').each(function(){
  $(this).find('a').attr('href', 'NEW_HREF');
});
```

This will select the last 'td' in each row and find the a element within it and replace the href with whatever you put in place of 'NEW_HREF'

You need to include jQuery which can be done by inserting the following into the  section of your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, no I am not using jQuery

Comment: As I had not too many answer I have tried your solution I got an erro saing: _Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function_

Comment: Right, you have to include jQuery to make my solution work. I'll edit my answer to include the link in case you want to try it.